# Print a 2d list from a class in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, class

```
class Mobile:
    def __init__(self, model, type, year):
        self.model = model
        self.type = type
        self.year = year

mobilePhones = [
    ["Samsung", "Galaxy S8", "2000"],
    ["Samsung", "Galaxy S9", "2001"],
    ["Samsung", "Galaxy S10", "2002"],
    ["Apple", "iPhone 8", "2005"],
    ["Apple", "iPhone 10", "2006"],
    ["Apple", "iPhone 11", "2007"],
]

phones = [
    Mobile(mobilePhones[0][0],mobilePhones[0][1],mobilePhones[0][2]),
    Mobile(mobilePhones[1][0], mobilePhones[1][1], mobilePhones[1][2]),
    Mobile(mobilePhones[2][0], mobilePhones[2][1], mobilePhones[2][2]),
    Mobile(mobilePhones[3][0], mobilePhones[3][1], mobilePhones[3][2]),
    Mobile(mobilePhones[4][0], mobilePhones[4][1], mobilePhones[4][2]),
    Mobile(mobilePhones[5][0], mobilePhones[5][1], mobilePhones[5][2]),
]

print(phones.model)
```

I'm just wondering why this logic doesn't work? I am trying to add each data in the 2dlist to the class so I'll be able to call all the model, type or year.

`print(mobilePhones[0][1])` works but not when I try to call it from the class. Like:

```
print(phones.model) or print(phones.year).
```

Comment: Also, save yourself some effort: `phones = [Mobile(*item) for item in mobilePhones]`

Answer (score 0):

Because `phones` is a `list` object.
You need to access its ordered contents/objects via indexing/looping. Then on those content/object, you can invoke the callable it provides.

Answer (score 0):

You are not trying to access it from the class with `phones.model`. You are trying to access it from the list. You need to select an index first, i.e. `phones[0].model`. Or if you want to print the model of all of them,

```py
for phone in phones:
    print(phone.model)
```